# Exporting documents stored inside SQL Server database to AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, powershell, amazon-s3, blob

We have a SQL Server/Windows (2016) database that stores documents inside BLOB (nvarbinary) fields. We are looking to migrate these documents out of the database and store them in AWS S3 storage.

I have been able to read BLOB data out of SQL Server in Powershell using stream read/write to a local file system and I can then use AWS S3 CP ... to get the files out to S3. However, this approach causes a need for an extra step - to store the file locally, on the SQL Server drive.

Is there a way to read binary data out of SQL Server database and store it directly in S3? I tried Write-S3Object, but it looks like it is expecting text (system.String) for contents, which is not working with images/pdfs and other non-text type documents we have.

Any suggestions, Powershell code samples, or references are much appreciated!

Thank you in advance

--Alex

Comment: The [AWS Tools for PowerShell docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-s3-upload-object.html) have a sample which uses the Write-S3Object cmdlet to upload a file from your local file system to an Amazon S3 bucket. Could you add that to your existing script?

Comment: Have you tried the `-Stream` version of `Write-S3Object`? You can feed it a `System.IO.MemoryStream` initialized from the `byte[]` that's returned for the `varbinary(max)` column in your select statement.

Comment: Tried setting up `-Stream`. It ended up being much slower (10x), to process a single BLOB at a time and send up to AWS S3. Was worth a try. Generating all files locally and then doing a mass copy up with `aws s3 cp` is the winner, albeit at the expense of space on the SQL Server's local drive.

Comment: You may have an older version of AWSPowerShell. At one point it was much, much slower than awscli but modern versions are comparable.

Comment: Seems fine:
`aws-cli/2.2.26 Python/3.8.8 Windows/10 exe/AMD64 prompt/off`